# fetching json data and creating a list

Tags: json, list, flutter

I'm currently studying flutter and I'm creating an app on my own...
So the problem at the moment is that I need to fetch json data and to put it in the list, in this case *listOfCards* (custom made object Card contains *initialSearch* as String and *results* as List. I've been following this example https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing#convert-the-response-into-a-list-of-photos but there they are directly parsing data into app and I really didn't know how to use it in my case.
I need to fill this *listOfCards* List to use it later in the app.
So here's the code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

List<Card> listOfCards = [];

Future<List<Card>> fetchCards(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client.get(
    Uri.parse('605a2f18b11aba001745dbdd.mockapi.io/api/v1/cards'),
  );

  return parseCards(response.body);
}

List<Card> parseCards(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Card>((json) => Card.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class Card {
  String initialSearch;
  List<String> mostPopularSearches;

  Card({
    this.initialSearch,
    this.mostPopularSearches,
  });

  factory Card.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Card(
      initialSearch: json['search'] as String,
      mostPopularSearches: json['results'] as List,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Custome class**

```
class Card {
  String initialSearch;
  List<String> mostPopularSearches;

  Card({this.initialSearch, this.mostPopularSearches});

  Card.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    initialSearch = json['initialSearch'];
    mostPopularSearches = json['mostPopularSearches'].cast<String>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['initialSearch'] = this.initialSearch;
    data['mostPopularSearches'] = this.mostPopularSearches;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Generated using [Json to dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

**To store the responses as Card object**

```
Card _card = Card.fromJson(responsebody);
```

**Your response JSON**

```
{
    "initialSearch": "Google",
    "mostPopularSearches": [
        "Google",
        "Facebook",
        "Stacjoverflow",
        "Reddit"
    ]
}
```